# why php header("location...") executes at end of script?

Tags: php, redirect, header

here is a simple script I've tested:

```
<?php

require 'dbcon.php';

header("location:http://google.com");

$time1 = time();

for($i=0;$i<=9999999;$i++){
    $j += $i * $i * $i * $i;
}

$time2 = time();

$total = $time2-$time1;

mysql_query("insert into test values('$total')");

?>
```

this script takes about 15 seconds to execute ( so 15 is inserted in my **test** table ) and after these seconds , the page redirects too the specified domain.

my question is why this happens?

in my real code, I want to redirect user to a webpage and then execute remaining code and store in database, so the user doesn't have to wait a lot. how would it be done?

**UPDATE1:**
please answer this question:
i want to first redirect the user , then insert data to mysql. for example i first get user's ip. then i want to redirect him , then detect user country from his ip and so on , then insert information into mysql. is it possible in someway?

**UPDATE2:**
i want to get user's country and region from another site with **curl** extension and then store in database. so it takes some seconds...

Comment: If you redirected the user away from your page, then you have already terminated the script and, therefore, cannot complete the execution of the remaining code.

Comment: When you have a header() location change, that prevents the rest of the script from executing.

Comment: Issuing a header like that makes it a race condition. The receiving browser will get that redirect and close the current condition, which will kill your script. Once you issue the header, you've got an unknown amount of time to finish your work. @palladium: simply calling header doesn't start a redirect - it won't start until the header is actually sent to the client, which can be "now" or "later".

Comment: @MarcB I don't believe, in this case, that the header is actually sent until the response body is.  Although this can very depending on how output buffering is configured.

Comment: sending headers for redirect does not terminate remaining code as also mentioned in same quesions

Comment: The correct way to do this is to insert a task into a work queue (like beanstalkd) and let a background worker process external to your httpd process the task.

Comment: @FrankFarmer : would you please explain more and in details ? how to do that?

Comment: In your question you say "...and so on", but what do you want to do that takes so long to execute?

Comment: i want to get user's country and region from another site with **curl** extension and then store in database. so it takes some seconds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`header("Location: ...");` just sets a header, nothing more. This is why you should always `exit` or `die()` after setting a Location header, unless you know exactly what you are getting yourself into by not doing it.

As for what you're trying to do, it's a bad idea. Deliberately having a request take 15 seconds is just asking for a DOS attack.

Comment: so how can I do that? i want to first redirect the user , then insert data to mysql. for example i first get user's ip. then i want to redirect him , then detect user country from his ip and so on , then insert information into mysql. is it possible in someway?

Comment: Anyone else think `exit(0)` is good practice?  I know `exit === exit(0)` but worth pointing out maybe.

Comment: @ali No PHP page should take more than a fraction of a second to run. Adding a row to the database before redirecting should make no difference.

Comment: i want to get user's country and region from another site with **curl** extension and then store in database. so it takes some seconds. so how?

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead:

```php
header("location:http://google.com");
exit;
```

Exiting after calling the header works.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: no relationship with my qustion